# obtener archivo en formato JSON de peticion XMLHttpRequest con una Promesa JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promesas

tengo la siguiente llamada a un API mediante una Promesa, necesito obtener el resultado de la llamada en un JSON en vez de texto, para así poder trabajar con el mismo, como seria posible? gracias!

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

    const c = (x) => console.log(x);

    function consultarApi(requestUrl){
        return new Promise( resolve =>{
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    resolve(this.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
            xhttp.send();
        });
    } 

    async function traerApi(_requesUrl){
        try {
            var profile = await consultarApi(_requesUrl);
            // c('Profile : ');
            c(profile);
        } catch (error){
            c(error);
        }
    }

    traerApi('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/');



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

he podido lograrlo con el metodo `parse()` de la siguiente manera;

```
resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
```

listo, obtengo la respuesta en formato `JSON`

gracias!